# How to set width using the maximum value of an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to render an output like the one in the picture

[image]

Right now, I am trying to pass all the numeric values into an array, and then set the grey bars' lengths to the maximum of those values
This is what I have so far, but it is not passing any values:

```js
var contentValues = $('facet-amount').text();
var arr = parseInt(contentValues);
$(".facet-percentage").width(Math.max(...arr));
```

```css
.facet {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  margin-top: 13px;
}
.facet-title {
  display: inline-block;
}
.facet-amount {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
}
.facet-percentage {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #e5e5e5);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-type-facet" class="facet">
  <div class="facet-header">
    <h3>Content Type</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Chapter</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">400</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Article</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">200</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Reference Work Entry</span>
    <span class="facet-amount" id='ciao'>207</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Protocol</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">16</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Book</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .facet-amount, with dot... and console.log(arr) then...

Comment: So all `.facet-percentage` should be 400px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your are missing the dot in the selector of `facet-amount` in `var contentValues = $('facet-amount').text();` it should be `var contentValues = $('.facet-amount').text();`.

Second, The `$('.facet-amount').text();` won't return an array, instead it will return the `text` of the first element matching that selector, which is 400 in your case. To select all values you need to use `$.each` as an example, and after filling your array you can use the `max` function.

See the following as an example:

```js
var arr = [];
$.each($('.facet-amount'), function(index, value) {
  arr[index] = parseInt($(value).text());
});
var max = Math.max(...arr);
console.log(max);
$(".facet-percentage").width(max);
```

```css
.facet {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  margin-top: 13px;
}
.facet-title {
  display: inline-block;
}
.facet-amount {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
}
.facet-percentage {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #e5e5e5);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-type-facet" class="facet">
  <div class="facet-header">
    <h3>Content Type</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Chapter</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">400</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Article</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">200</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Reference Work Entry</span>
    <span class="facet-amount" id='ciao'>207</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Protocol</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">16</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Book</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But looking at your image, I think your intent is to set each one of the `facets` to its value, not the max of all, see this as a suggestion:

```js
$('.facet-amount').each(function(index, element) {
  var $el = $(element);
  $el.siblings(".facet-percentage").width(parseInt($el.text()));
});
```

```css
.facet {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  margin-top: 13px;
}
.facet-title {
  display: inline-block;
}
.facet-amount {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
}
.facet-percentage {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #e5e5e5);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-type-facet" class="facet">
  <div class="facet-header">
    <h3>Content Type</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Chapter</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">400</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Article</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">200</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Reference Work Entry</span>
    <span class="facet-amount" id='ciao'>207</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Protocol</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">16</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="facet-percentage" style=""></span>
    <span class="facet-title">Book</span>
    <span class="facet-amount">2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra part! The documentation says that `parseInt()` <parses a string argument and returns an integer>. Why is it interpreted as a value in `px` then?

Comment: Referring to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) of the `$.width` function, if you pass a numeric value it will consider it as 'px' by default, if other values are intended it should be used explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to rescale those values from 1-100% 'cause otherwise they go out of bounds in my original case.

Comment: Then calculate the max first, and use a percentage out of the max, something like:
 `$el.siblings(".facet-percentage").width((parseInt($el.text()) / max) + '%')`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `.` in your class selector, and also your parseInt is incorrect, it will work only on the first element of the array.

Try this:

```
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, $('.facet-amount').map(function(){return +$(this).text();}).get());
$(".facet-percentage").width(maxValue);
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/LoLgz6wv/

Comment: Didn't downvoted, but i guess that your sentence about Math.max fail was the reason... Actually, Math.max with spread syntax works fine with arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 0):

In your code arr has a type of number.

You must create an array:

```
var arr = []; //empty array

$('facet-amount').each(function(){
  arr.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
 }

$(".facet-percentage").width(Math.max.apply(null, arr));
```